# Connecting Hive to SpagoBI:org.eclipse.birt.report.data.oda.jdbc.JDBCException: No suitable driver

Tags: hive

I am trying to connect the spagoBI studio to hive.
But when I try to add a data source for the hive server, I faced the following exception when I test the connection.

> org.eclipse.birt.report.data.oda.jdbc.JDBCException: No suitable driver.
>                   at org.eclipse.birt.report.data.oda.jdbc.JDBCDriverManager.testConnection(JDBCDriverManager.java:729)
>                   at org.eclipse.birt.report.data.oda.jdbc.ui.util.DriverLoader.testConnection(DriverLoader.java:147)
>                   at org.eclipse.birt.report.data.oda.jdbc.ui.util.DriverLoader.testConnection(DriverLoader.java:138)
>                   at org.eclipse.birt.report.data.oda.hive.ui.profile.HiveSelectionPageHelper.testConnection(HiveSelectionPageHelper.java:404)
>                   at org.eclipse.birt.report.data.oda.hive.ui.profile.HiveSelectionPageHelper.access$4(HiveSelectionPageHelper.java:392)
>                   at org.eclipse.birt.report.data.oda.hive.ui.profile.HiveSelectionPageHelper$2.widgetSelected(HiveSelectionPageHelper.java:333)
>                   at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:234)
>                   at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
>                   at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1053)
>                   at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4066)
>                   at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3657)
>                   at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.runEventLoop(Window.java:825)
>                   at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.open(Window.java:801)
>                   at org.eclipse.birt.report.designer.data.ui.actions.NewDataSourceAction.run(NewDataSourceAction.java:126)
>                   at org.eclipse.jface.action.Action.runWithEvent(Action.java:498)
>                   at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.handleWidgetSelection(ActionContributionItem.java:584)
>                   at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.access$2(ActionContributionItem.java:501)
>                   at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem$5.handleEvent(ActionContributionItem.java:411)
>                   at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
>                   at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1053)
>                   at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4066)
>                   at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3657)
>                   at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runEventLoop(Workbench.java:2640)
>                   at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runUI(Workbench.java:2604)
>                   at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.access$4(Workbench.java:2438)
>                   at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$7.run(Workbench.java:671)
>                   at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
>                   at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:664)
>                   at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
>                   at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:115)
>                   at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
>                   at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
>                   at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
>                   at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:369)
>                   at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:179)
>                   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>                   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>                   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
>                   at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:620)
>                   at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:575)
>                   at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1408)
>                   at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1384)

Kindly Help.

Answer (score 0):

while creating the database connection "**GenericJDBC**" in the connection profiles while creating the connection, and click next.
Provide all the details in the **General Tab** and click on the triangle above **add jars**:-
*hive-jdbc,
hive-exec,
hive-metastore,
hive-service,
libfb,
libthrift,
hive-common,
commons-logging,
slf4j.api,
hadoop-core,
hadoop-common,
hadoop-thriftfs,
commons-cli,
log4j,
guava,
commons-collections,
commons-configurations,
hadoop-auth,
hadoop-hdfs*

I have not mentioned the versions of the jars because I do not know which ones you are using on your side.
you may have to look into your hadoop and hive versions to find the versions of the above stated jars.
In proerties tab provide all the details as applicable.

For selecting the driver, In the properties tab, click on the button with 3 dots(...) next to the Driver option and goto "**browse for class**" option.
It will show all the available drivers from the list of jars.
From there, depending on the version of the hiveserver that you are using select the corresponding driver.
For hive2 :-select "**org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver**".
otherwise :- select "**org.apache.hadoop.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver**"

then click OK and Test Connection.

I hope it helps.